# Obtaining item index in ranged based for on vector

Tags: c++, c++11, ranged-loops

The C++11 introduced ranged-based for loop that is internally implemented using (const) iterators so this:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;

for(std::string &str : vec)
{
//...
}
```

is basically equivalent to more verbose (yes, it could be simplified using `auto`):

```
for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
//...
}
```

However commonly one needs an index of the item as well. With the second approach that is easy:

```
auto index = it - vec.begin();
```

In ranged-based `for` it is not so straightforward. But **I was wondering if this was ok and portable solution** that avoids iterators altogether:

```
for(auto &str : vec)
{
    auto index = &str - &vec[0];
}
```

(`const` version will be the same but one needs to watch out not to mix non-`const` container with const reference which might not always be obvious.)

Obviously this relies on several assumptions:

- that iterator of vector is just a reference to an item (probably in the standard?)
- container is guaranteed contiguous (`std::vector` is...)
- the internal implementation of ranged based for (also probably in the standard)

Comment: First loop is not equivalent - you copy every value while iterating. If you use `auto` anyway you better use `auto` for `index` rather than `int`

Comment: @Slava Fair points. I will update the OP accordingly.

Comment: Technically, your proposed C++11 for loop copies every string in `vec` (other than with the iterator-based version). You should use `for(std::string const& str : vec)` or `for(auto const& str : vec)` for read-only access instead.

Comment: Shameless plug for [cppitertools `iter::enumerate`](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools#enumerate)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, but I'd use `vec.data()` instead.  A bonus of using `.data()` is that non-contiguous `std` containers don't have it, so your code reliably stops compiling when the container being iterated over doesn't work that way (like `deque` or `std::vector<bool>`).  (There are other minor advantages, like `std::addressof` issues, and the fact it is well defined on empty containers, but those aren't as important especially here.)

Alternatively we write an `index_t` iterator-like wrapper:

```
template<class T>
struct index_t {
  T t;
  T operator*()const{ return t; }
  void operator++() { ++t; }
  friend bool operator==( index_t const& lhs, index_t const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.t == rhs.t;
  }
  friend bool operator!=( index_t const& lhs, index_t const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.t != rhs.t;
  }
};
template<class T>
index_t<T> index(T t) { return {t}; }
```

`index_t<int>` can be used to create counting `for(:)` loops.

`index_t<iterator>` can be used to create iterator-returning `for(:)` loops.

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b,e;
  It begin() const {return b;}
  It end() const {return e;}
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It s, It f ) { return {s,f}; }

template<class T>
range_t<index_t<T>>
index_over( T s, T f ) {
  return {{{s}}, {{f}}};
}
template<class Container>
auto iterators_of( Container& c ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  return index_over( begin(c), end(c) );
}
```

we can now iterator over iterators of a container.

```
for (auto it : iterators_of(vec))
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4de64b26bdb213f).

---

The mentioned iterate-over-integers is:

```
for (int i : index_over( 0, 100 ) )
```

we can also directly get the indexes of the container:

```
template<class Container>
range_t< index_t<std::size_t> >
indexes_of( Container& c ) {
  return index_over( std::size_t(0), c.size() );
}
template<class T, std::size_t N>
range_t< index_t<std::size_t> >
indexes_of( T(&)[N] ) {
  return index_over( std::size_t(0), N );
}
```

which lets us:

```
for( auto i : indexes_of( vec ) )
```

where `i` varies from `0` to `vec.size()-1`.  I find this is easier to work with sometimes than a zip iterator or the like.

---

Improvements omitted:

Make `index_t` a real `input_iterator`.  Use `std::move` and/or `std::forward` as needed in making indexes and ranges.  Support Sentinals on ranges.  Make `range_t` interface richer (`size`, optional random-access `[]`, `empty`, `front`, `back`, `range_t range_t::without_front(n) const`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's a valid solution. The underlying data is guaranteed to be contiguous (`std::vector` is supposed to be a dynamic array, more or less).

> n4140 §23.3.6.1 [vector.overview]/1
>
> The elements of a `vector` are stored contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`

Comment: Interesting point there `T is some type other than bool` because iirc with bool `std::vector` becomes basically a bit array and my solution will likely NOT work then...

Comment: Yes, `vector<bool>` is a mistake that we can't get rid of. It's a nice class, but it's not a `vector`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wrote "smaller than an `int` can hold" when the solution OP asked about was `auto index = &str - &vec[0];`. Why does the difference of two pointers have to do with int? Wouldn't auto deduce to a `std::ptrdiff_t`?

Comment: @NirFriedman because when I was writing this post the OP stated `int index = ...`. Fixed.

Comment: @NirFriedman It was pointed out that having int there was sub-optimal plus some other minor issue and I have corrected both, see comments to OP.

Comment: @krzaq my bad; +1'ed.