# Tuple of vectors and push back

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I have a tuple of vectors, I would like to `push_back()` each value from an initializer list into the corresponding vector in the "vectors tuple". The `create()` function in the code is where I would like to do this.

```
template<typename...Fields>
class ComponentManager
{
  using Index = int;
public:
  /**
   * Provides a handle to a component
   **/
  struct ComponentHandle {
    static constexpr Index Nil = -1;
    bool nil() { return index == Nil; }
    const Index index;
  };

  ComponentHandle lookup(Entity e) { 
    return ComponentHandle{get(m_map,e,-1)}; 
  }

  template<int i>
  auto get(ComponentHandle handle) {
    return std::get<i>(m_field)[handle.index];
  }

  ComponentHandle create(Entity e, Fields ...fields) {
    m_entity.push_back(e);
    // m_fields.push_back ... ???
  }

private:
  std::vector<Entity>                m_entity;
  std::tuple<std::vector<Fields>...> m_field;
  std::map<Entity,Index>             m_map;
};
```

Example:

```
Entity e1, e2;
ComponentManager<int,float,int> cm{};
cm.create(e1, 42, 1337.0, 99);
cm.create(e2, 84, 2674.0, 198);
// Resulting contents of cm.m_field tuple
// { 
//    vector<int>   [ 42, 84 ], 
//    vector<float> [ 1337.0, 2674.0 ]
//    vector<int>   [ 99, 198 ]
// }
```

Comment: You have a `tuple` of vectors, not a vector of tuples. Can you clarify your question with some example input and desired output?

Comment: I fixed that and also clarified that it is an initializer list and not a tuple that the values are to be retrieved from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void for_each_argument(F f, Args&&... args) {
    (void) std::initializer_list<int>{(f(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};
}

ComponentHandle create(Entity e, Fields ...fields) 
{
    for_each_argument([&](auto field)
                  { 
                      using field_type = std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(field)>>;
                      std::get<field_type>(m_field).push_back(field); 
                  },
                  fields...);
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/a8L3tRoWMuMgtnAx)

---

> I didn't mention in the question that it is a requirement that the fields can be the same type, so there can be several vector's in the tuple for example.

```
template <typename TVec, typename TFieldTuple, std::size_t... TIdxs>
void expander(TVec& vec, TFieldTuple ft, std::index_sequence<TIdxs...>)
{
    for_each_argument([&](auto idx)
    {
        std::get<idx>(vec).push_back(std::get<idx>(ft));
    }, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, TIdxs>{}...);
}

const auto create = [](auto& vec, auto ...fields) 
{
    expander(vec, 
             std::make_tuple(fields...), 
             std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(fields)>());
};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1aPnOqTbzTx0DErR)

Comment: I didn't mention in the question that it is a requirement that the fields can be the same type, so there can be several vector<int>'s in the tuple for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it works like a charm! I envy your C++ knowledge

Answer (score 3):

It may not be readily obvious, but the way to unpack a tuple in C++ is to use `std::apply()`. With C++17, this is as easy as:

```
void create(Entity e, Fields ...fields) {
    m_entity.push_back(e);
    std::apply([&](auto&... vs) {
       (vs.push_back(fields), ...);
    }, m_field);
}
```

With C++14, I'd suggest implementing `apply()` yourself anyway (it's a [short function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)), and then you need to use the [expander trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30563282/2069064) instead of using fold-expressions:

```
void create(Entity e, Fields ...fields) {
    m_entity.push_back(e);
    not_std::apply([&](auto&... vs) {
       using swallow = int[];
       (void)swallow{0, 
           (vs.push_back(fields), 0)...
           };
    }, m_field);
}
```

With C++11, most of the same applies, except we can't use generic lambdas and implementing `std::apply` is more verbose (but not more complicated) than in the linked reference. Thankfully, we don't actually need to for anything other than making the code shorter - we know all the vector types:

```
void create(Entity e, Fields ...fields) {
    m_entity.push_back(e);
    not_std::apply([&](std::vector<Fields>&... vs) {
       using swallow = int[];
       (void)swallow{0, 
           (vs.push_back(fields), 0)...
           };
    }, m_field);
}
```

Comment: What, no love for `index_over`?

Comment: @Yakk What, from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39981155/2069064)? Isn't that a runtime thing?

Comment: nm, looks like I ended up using index over to implement apply to implement for_each_tuple_element.

Comment: Nope, I spoke too soon.  `apply` is needed for `for_each_tuple_element`, but you can solve the OP's problem without using `apply`.  Now that I look at your answer, I do like how you have explited the fact that `vs` and `fields` are the same size, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

C++14 solution that implements `apply` from C++17 half way down.

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index{};

template<class=void,std::size_t...Is>
auto index_over( std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto) {
    return decltype(f)(f)( index<Is>... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_over( index_t<N> ={} ) {
  return index_over( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}


template<class F>
auto for_each_arg( F&& f ) {
  return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto) {
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{0,(void(
      f(decltype(args)(args))
    ),0)...};
  };
}
```

These are useful, but not needed:

```
template<class F, class Tuple>
decltype(auto) apply( F&& f, Tuple&& tuple ) {
  auto count = index< std::tuple_size< std::decay_t<Tuple> >{} >;
  return index_over( count )( [&](auto...Is) {
    using std::get;
    return std::forward<F>(f)( get<decltype(Is)::value>( std::forward<Tuple>(tuple) )... );
  } );
}
template<class Tuple>
auto for_each_tuple_element(Tuple&& tuple) {
  return [&](auto&& f)->decltype(auto){
    return apply(
      for_each_arg( decltype(f)(f) ),
      std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)
    );
  };
}
```

test code:

```
int main() {
    std::tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<char> > tup;
    for_each_tuple_element( tup )( [](auto&& v) {
      v.push_back(3);
    });
    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup).size() << "," << std::get<1>(tup).size() << "\n";
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2be5c9e1e8f81229)

Then we can apply it to your problem.

```
ComponentHandle create(Entity e, Fields ...fields) {
  m_entity.push_back(e);
  auto indexer = index_over<sizeof...(fields>();
  auto fields_tuple = std::forward_as_tuple( std::forward<Fields>(fields)... );
  indexer( for_each_arg([&](auto Is){
    std::get<Is>(m_fields).push_back(
      std::get<Is>(decltype(fields_tuple)(fields_tuple))
    );
  } );
}
```

`index_over` takes a compile-time N and returns a lambda.  This lambda takes a callable, and calls it with `index_t<0>` through `index_t<N-1>`.

`for_each_arg` takes a callable, and returns a lambda that takes any number of arguments.  It calls the callable with each of those arguments in turn.

Stitched together we take our `Fields...fields`, build an `index_over` it to get us a compile-time set of indexes into it.  We then store those Fields in a `tuple` of r and l value references.

We write an operation on a single index `Is`.  We then pass that to `for_each_arg`, and pass the return value to the `index_over`, and get the single index-handling lambda to be called for each index.

Some compilers don't permit a non-`constexpr` `std::integral_constant` to convert to a scalar in a `constexpr` context.  They are wrong and/or obsolete.  For those, you'll have to do `decltype(Is)::value`.